# Several ways (in context of tenses) to express planned near future actions

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, present-tense

I am reading a English book and in simple present tense section it is mentioned that simple present tense can be used to express planned events of near future, but in present continuous section same thing is mentioned for present continuous as well.

So, my question is whether both of below sentences are grammatically correct?

- I leave for New York tomorrow
- I am leaving to New York tomorrow

---

**UPDATE:**

I did more research and it looks like planned near future actions can be expressed using simple present, simple future and present continuous. So, all below examples are correct:

- PM leaves for US tomorrow
- PM is leaving for US tomorrow
- PM will leave for US tomorrow
- PM will be leaving for US tomorrow

**Could someone please confirm/correct my understanding.**

*P.S.: Actually I am preparing for an English Grammar exam so want to know technically correct/acceptable usage, and not colloquial usage.*

Comment: leaving _for_ just like the first sentence. Otherwise, in simple present the destination is more topical; with progressive the act of leaving. Both are grammatical when you change the preposition.

Comment: You may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: @KarlG Could you please explain in bit simple language, I really didn't get your point.

Comment: 1) _leaving to New York_ is non-idiomatic; you _leave for_. If you say, _I am leaving for New York tomorrow_, the act of leaving is the slightly more important information. "Can you come to dinner?" Most people would answer, "No, I'm leaving for New York tomorrow.” The act of leaving (and so can't come to dinner) is the important information. "I leave for New York tomorrow" would more likely answer the question "When are you leaving." or "Where are going?"

Comment: @KarlG Ok, thank you so much, understood. One just one question - is it grammatically correct to use simple future tense as well for planned near future actions (like saying "I will leave for NYC tomorrow"? Or is it that planned near future actions should only be expressed using either simple present or present continuous? Actually I am preparing for an English Grammar so want to know technically correct/acceptable usage, and not colloquial usage.

Comment: @KarlG I have updated my question. I am wondering if you would like to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

There may be three correct sentences:
1.  'l am going to leave for NY tomorrow' /an intention to do this/.
2.  'l am leaving for NY tomorrow' /an arrangement made, i.e., the flight is reserved/.
3. 'I leave for NY tomorrow' /a trip schedule/.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply. If you could also attach some reference or reading then it would be helpful for me as a grammatical proof